# How to Inner Join on multiple columns with .Net LINQ method syntax in VB.Net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, join

I have a situation in which I need to use Expression Trees to dynamically build LINQ queries that join two DataTable objects at run time.  It appears that Expression Trees can only be constructed using method syntax (If I'm wrong about this please let me know). 
My current query is similar to this:

```
Dim result = From a In dataTable1
             Join b In dataTable2
                 On a.Item("Property1") Equals b.Item("Property1") And
                    a.Item("Property2") Equals b.Item("Property2") And
                    a.Item("Property3") Equals b.Item("Property3") And
             Select New With {
                .prop1 = a.Item("Property1")
                .prop2 = a.Item("Property2")
                .prop3 = b.Item("Property3")
                .prop4 = b.Item("Property4")
                .prop5 = b.Item("Property5")}
```

My question is this: how does one specify multiple columns of a composite key join using the method syntax of the Join clause?

Comment: I found a possible answer.  I will provide details after I verify it's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a property in the object being compared that is the conjoined "key", you can compare key-to-key in the join.

If the objects are the same type, you can also create a custom IEQualityComparer(of ...)

Answer (score 0):

Use anonymous objects for the equality comparison

```
Dim result = From a In dataTable1
             Join b In dataTable2
             On New With {
                 .p1 = a.Item("Property1"),
                 .p2 = a.Item("Property2"),
                 .p3 = a.Item("Property3")} _
             Equals New With {
                 .p1 = b.Item("Property1"),
                 .p2 = b.Item("Property2"),
                 .p3 = b.Item("Property3")}
             Select New With {
                 .prop1 = a.Item("Property1"),
                 .prop2 = a.Item("Property2"),
                 .prop3 = b.Item("Property3"),
                 .prop4 = b.Item("Property4"),
                 .prop5 = b.Item("Property5")}
```